# How do I reference types or modules defined in other F# files?

Tags: f#

I have the following in a .fs file:

```
namespace fsHoldem

module holdemPlayer

type Player()=
  ... etc...
```

and I'm trying to reference the type Player in another file.  I've tried using open:

```
namespace fsHoldem

module BetStrategies

open fsHoldem.holdemPlayer
```

but I'm getting the error "Namespace or module 'fsHoldem' is not defined."

Note that both .fs files share the same namespace, and both exist in the same project.