# F# Module/Namespace Error

Tags: f#

My first program with F#.

I have one file like so:

```
namespace LanguageMapper.Data


#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Data"
#r "System.Data.Linq"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders"
#endif

open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

module Data = 

    // You can use Server Explorer to build your ConnectionString. 
    type SqlConnection = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = @"connstring">
    let db = SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
```

Then i have another file like so

```
namespace LanguageMapper.Program

open Data

module Program = 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 


    let getLocale x = 
        match x with
        | [|"live"|] -> "live"
        | [|"dev"|] -> "dev"
        | _ -> "local"
```

Over top of the `open Data` i get a red squiggly in VS telling me:

> "Error   1   This declaration opens the namespace or module
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data' through a partially qualified path. Adjust
>   this code to use the full path of the namespace. This change will make
>   your code more robust as new constructs are added to the F# and CLI
>   libraries."

What am i doing wrong? I just want to reference one file from the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the module using its fully qualified name, that is including its namespace. So in `LanguageMapper.Program` you need to `open LanguageMapper.Data.Data` (only the last bit is the module name).

The Compiler is complaining on your `open` definition because it only specifies to open a namespace or module named Data - and it finds one in Microsoft.FSharp.Data, probably because there are some 'automatic' opens for the Microsoft.FSharp namespaces.

Comment: It was this, plus the fact that i had to manually rearrange the file order in the project file as pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608240/how-do-i-reference-types-in-different-f-files. Thank you!