# Access Class in a different Module

Tags: class, f#

Note: started F# 4 days back so consider before giving a negative vote please. Or at least let me know what i am doing wrong to receive all the negative Votes.

> Inteligence.fs

```
module Inteligence
open TTTAiFSharpAlphaBeta
open Boards

type Node(board: Board, moveBox :int, point:int)=
    let mutable _moveBox:int=moveBox
    let mutable _point:int=point
    let mutable _board=new Board(board)
    let mutable _parent= board

    new() = Node(new Board(),0,0)
    new(board: Board)= new Node(new Board(board),0,0)

    member this.MoveBox with get() = _moveBox and set(value) = _moveBox <- value
    member this.Point with get() = _point and set(value) = _point <- value
    member this.Board with get() = _board and set(value) = _board <- value
    member this.Parent with get() = _parent and set(value) = _parent <- value

    member this.Copy(node: Node)= 
             _board<- new Board(node.Board)
             _moveBox<- node.MoveBox
             _point<- node.Point
             _parent<- node.Parent




type Inteligence(board:Board,symbol:int)=
    let mutable _nodeCount=0;
    let mutable _rootNode= new Node(board)
    let mutable _level = 0
    let mutable _symbol = symbol
    let mutable _reff = new Boards.Reffery()

    member this.NodeCount with get() = _nodeCount and set(value) = _nodeCount <- value
    member this.RootNode with get() = _rootNode and set(value) = _rootNode <- value
    member this.Level with get() = _level and set(value) = _level <- value
    member this.Symbol with get() = _symbol and set(value) = _symbol <- value

    member this.Move() :int = 0
    member this.MinMaxAlphaBeta(node:Node, min:bool,  alpha:int,  beta:int):int=0
    member this.BoardPoint(node:Node):int=0
```

> AI.fs

```
    module TTTAiFSharpAlphaBeta
    open AIInterface
    open Boards
    type AI()= 
            let mutable cboard =new Board()
            let mutable level = 0
            let mutable symbol = 0
            interface IAI with
                member this.SetAi (_board: Board ,_level, _symbol)  =
                     cboard <- _board
                     level  <- _level
                     symbol <- _symbol
                member this.GetAiName()="F#AlphaBetaAi"
                member this.GetAiVersion()="0.0.1"
                member this.GetLevel()= [| 3 |];
                member this.AiMove()=
                           Inteligence.Inteligence(cboard,symbol).Move()
```

The problem is i can't access

```
Move()
```

from Inteligence.fs

```
member this.AiMove()=
         Inteligence.Inteligence(cboard,symbol).Move()
```

in AI.fs

Getting Error The namespace or module 'Inteligence' is not defined
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# defining and using a namespace in the same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172888/f-defining-and-using-a-namespace-in-the-same-project)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608240/how-do-i-reference-types-in-different-f-files - either way this is a dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using `fsi` (from the `#r`).

If you are you need to use

```
#load "Intelligence.fs"
```

If in visual studio you need to make sure Intelligence.fs is before the other file in the project list (F# is sensitive to the order files are compiled in)

Comment: @Taufiq Try `#load "file.fs"` - there was a typo in the original answer.

Comment: Nope thats not working either....and i dont need         
#if Board
        #r @"Boards.dll"
        #r @"AIInterface.dll"
        #endif
either to run

Comment: @Taufiq - are you running with the interactive shell or compiling?

Comment: @JohnPalmer compiling vs2012

Comment: @Taufiq - what is the order of files in your project? (as displayed in the list on the right hand side).  You need the `Intelligence.fs` file to be before the other file

Comment: Intelligence file is below Ai File how can you change the position of them?

Comment: @Taufiq Or alt-up and alt-down are normally the shortcut keys

Comment: @TomasPetricek We need to get a canonical answer to this up the pagerank - maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608240/how-do-i-reference-types-in-different-f-files, maybe others. (And stop answering the existing ones!)